Adjusting Mozilla extension: page action task for a target page
I'm trying to adjust simple Firefox extension: page_action for a particular page: when the user clicks the page action icon on that page, it should navigate to https://target-web-page.asp (i.e. action that is only relevant to particular page).
This just should replace manually copying and pasting link into the browser's address bar on that page. Preferably, I want modify the URL of the current page without reloading the page (change url portion after the domain).
here is manifest.json
{

  "description": "Adds page action icon to browser address bar",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "open-my-page",
  "version": "1.0",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com",
  "icons": {
    "40": "icons/love.jpg"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/love.jpg"
  },

  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "open-my-page@mozilla.org"
    }
  }

}

and background.js
function openMyPage() {
  console.log("injecting");
  window.open("https://target-web-page.asp","_self")

}
    
browser.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(openMyPage);

but this does't work. How to adjust this code to achieve the desired functionality?

It's unclear what the problem is. You can see how to declare page_action in MDN. To change the path portion you can use history.replaceState in the content script which you can inject with browser.tabs.executeScript.
